# How to configure Rails 5.2.1 server listen on all interfaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm still fairly new to RoR and learning so please bear with me if I have follow-up questions. Our Rails (v 5.0.2) app was configured to listen on all interfaces with this configuration in `config/boot.rb`:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      # make rails listen on all interfaces (accept connections from any ip)
      super.merge(Host: '0.0.0.0', Port: 1234)
    end
  end
end
```

I recently upgraded Rails from `5.0.2` to `5.2.1` and when I run `rails s`, I get:

```
/Users/aum/rails_app/config/boot.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands/server (LoadError)
    from /Users/aum/rails_app/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

So I updated the `'require'` to `rails/commands/server/server_command` and now I get

```
rails s
/Users/aum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails_app/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:110:in `<module:Command>': uninitialized constant Rails::Command::Base (NameError)
Did you mean?  Base64
  from /Users/aum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails_app/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:109:in `<module:Rails>'
  from /Users/aum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@rails_app/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/aum/rails_app/config/boot.rb:5:in `require'
  from /Users/aum/rails_app/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
  from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure how/where to specify the host and port in Rails 5.2.1 since the `default_options` definitions has also changed here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb#L68

NOTE: I can start the server with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 1234` but that is not what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma), which is the default HTTP server for Rails 5, the binding options are defined in [`config/puma.rb`](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/3d24dc5936d0e570376fa843a682cf2c5481041e/lib/puma/dsl.rb#L199-L224):

```
bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'
```

Comment: Just in case it helps others, I had to update my `puma` gem from `4.x` to `5.x` and then removed `preload_app!` from `config/puma.rb`.