# How to make a rails app listening to all interfaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, dokku

My rails server in production is rejecting connections for reasons I do not understand.
When I try to connect via browser I receive the following error message from Chromium:

```
This site can’t be reached. cinemeeting.eu refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
```

The only help I received so far is from josegonzalez at [GitHub](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/3839) who suggested my application should listen to all interfaces and respect the PORT environment variable.
My `config/puma.rb` file is, as suggested by [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#config), the following:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/
  # deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

How can I check if puma is listening to all interfaces? 
josegonzalez also suggested [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52788415/5078888) at Stackoverflow, however I do not understand why the bind is applied to port 3000.

I have deployed my application to [NetCup](https://www.netcup.eu/), a German hosting provider, via [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku), following instructions at the [Dokku documentation](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/).

Comment: Port 3000 is only used for local development. Heroku will supply the correct `PORT` environment variable. What URL are you using to connect? Are you using `http` or `https`? Can you connect using your myappname.herokuapp.com domain? If so, cinemeeting.eu is not set up correctly. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: I use dokku-letsencrypt. The url I use to connect is `cinemeeting.eu`, which is automatically translated to `https://cinemeeting.eu/`. So, instead of using `bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'` what am I expected to use?

Comment: I would make the `https` explicit just to be sure. Port 3000 is only used for development, if you have that hard coded that's likely going to be a problem. We'd need to see more of your config and information about your hosting to help. "Listening on all interfaces" sounds like a red herring.

Comment: I still have to edit `config/puma.rb`, so the bind line of code is not yet insered. Can you be more explicit about the information you need?. I already inserted `config/puma.rb` in my question, what else can be useful?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know dokku. I can't say exactly what info is needed because there's too many things which could have gone wrong; puma is just one piece. Your deployment might have failed. Your DNS could be wrong. Your app might be misconfigured, or not starting at all. First thing I'd check is if your app is running at all, and what is in `ENV`. Can you get a Rails console?

Comment: Sure, I can get a Rails console

Comment: HTTP is usually mapped to port 80, HTTPS to port 443. Rails uses 3000 in development as its not usually occupied and thus won't collide with other software like nginx or apache and you don't need root privileges. But of course you need to check with your actual host which port is used and the provide it via `ENV['PORT']`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that `cinemeeting.eu` does not point to your Heroku server. `dig cinemeeting.eu` reveals that it's pointing to `5.252.227.76` which is not Heroku.

Try connecting to your herokuapp.com domain. It will be `your-app-name.herokuapp.com`. Make sure you're using `https`. If that works it means your app is working fine and it's a DNS problem. Follow the instructions in [Custom Domain Names for Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) to point `cinemeeting.eu` to your Heroku app.

> I do not understand why the bind is applied to port 3000.

That is only used for local development. `http://localhost:3000`. On Heroku it will use the `PORT` environment variable supplied by Heroku.

Comment: I have not deployed my application to Heroku. I used instead dokku to deploy at NetCup, a German provider.

Comment: @Asarluhi Don't follow Heroku's instructions if you're not on Heroku. Heroku acts rather differently from other hosting. We can better answer if you add information about your deployment to your question, as well the information I asked about in the comment.